# Lines starting with a number break the code formatting

Tags: support, code-formatting

Lines starting with a number break the code formatting

1375202508
    this is the second line

vs

```
this is the first line
```

1375202508 <-- second line
    Third line

---

What the above looks like in edit mode:

[image]

Comment: I'm kind of confused. I went to the edit field to test this and, sure enough, there were four spaces. So I deleted the spaces and added four more...now it works.

Comment: That is odd @ಠ_ಠ

Comment: why do you keep reverting changes!!

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ - Your changes break the example, that's probably why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first spaces were `&#160;`, AKA No Break Space - these are not your regular spaces (ASCII 32).

Changing to normal spaces makes it work alright.

So, with the spaces being char 160:

1375202508
    this is the second line

And without:

```
1375202508
this is the second line
```

Comment: Oded -- I am using the spacebar on my keyboard...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - No copy pasta?

Comment: See this example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18109221/561731

Comment: No copy/paste at all!

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - That example also starts with char 160.

Comment: Very odd... I cannot replicate it again...

Comment: Maybe a Ctrl/Alt/Other modifier key stuck a bit?

Comment: Idk... I do not think so....